# Reaction of coumarin with phenylmagnesium bromide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds, grignard-reagent

I came across this problem..

[image: Treatment of coumarin with phenylmagnesium bromide]

I thought that the Grignard reagent, PhMgBr, would cleave the lactone and then subsequently add to the ketone formed, giving an allylic tertiary alcohol after aqueous workup. Treatment with acid would then lead to intramolecular etherification, giving 2,2-diphenyl-2​*H*-1-benzopyran:

[image: Proposed mechanism]

But then our chemistry professor gave out a different mechanism for this reaction as follows.

[image: Questionable taught mechanism]

What is the correct product?

Comment: I immediately call BS on this. You can argue for the conjugate addition step, but you shouldn't argue for a $\mathrm{S_N2}$ at a $\mathrm{sp^2}$ carbon except under very special circumstances (which this reaction does not fit)...

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't any examples of coumarins being treated with aryl Grignards, so this is again a made up question. I much prefer your mechanism, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of *regioselectivity*, at least for the first addition of the Grignard reagent, I suggest to have a look on the cumarin, that may be seen as an α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compound. Hard nucleophiles (in terms of HSAB principle) like $\ce{MeLi}$ would almost exclusively react with the carbonyl carbon, as you drew in your reaction equation.  Soft nucleophiles, such as cuprates, would prefer the 1,4-addition.

Going from $\ce{MeMgBr}$, to $\ce{EtMgBr}$, $\ce{i-PrMgBr}$, and $\ce{t-BuMgBr}$ gradually lowers the polarity of the bond between the metal (magnesium) and the directly attached carbon atom.  Hence, along with this line (in other words, as a trend), the preference to react in 1,4-position  (more like Michael reaction) increases *on expense* of the reaction of this nucleophile on the carbonyl carbon.  I *speculate* the bond in the Grignard reagent, between $\ce{Mg}$ and the phenyl group in $\ce{PhMgBr}$, is even less polarised, than in the instance of $\ce{t-BuMgBr}$, and hence conclude at least a significant portion of the product of the first addition formed will be the one of the 1,4-addition (second drawing).

As @Zhe, I however still have a difficulty to understand the subsequently suggested *second* addition of $\ce{PhMgBr}$ in the lower drawing, because the activation of the double bond once in conjugation with the carbonyl group is gone.

Comment: OK... So this has to do something with the HSAB theory. I shall go through. Thanks for the response.

Comment: But can you please say me why hard nucleophiles prefer attacking carbonyl carbon and soft nucleophiles prefer 1,4 addition?

Comment: @SurajS There are several factors which will be explained in detail in textbooks about organometallic chemistry.  Among the more important contributions is the ratio of charge/polarisation at a site of a reagent and size/volume over which the charge is distributed.  *J. Chem. Educ.*, **1978**, *55*, 355-360 (DOI 10.1021/ed055p355), or https://retrosynthetix.com/2017/03/01/acid-base-xi/ may provide some insight.

Comment: It's drawn like a pseudo SN2,  but given that you can delocalise across the oxygen and double, coupled with the nature of the.Grignard,  it's not an SN2, but the outcome can be the same

Comment: In the second mechanism the second addition of PhMgBr may be OK if one first eliminates to a ketene and then adds PhMgBr.

Answer (score 4):

A search of Chemical Abstracts for the OP's reaction of coumarin **5** with phenyl magnesium bromide forming 2,2-diphenyl-2H-chromene had 216 substructure hits but none from coumarin itself. Two typical examples are shown below.<sup>[1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ol0619260)</sup> Suraj S is vindicated!
[image]

Although the OP's professor's proposed product **10** of the reaction is well-known, a search did not produce its formation from coumarin. There were no substructure hits either. If the reaction mixture were to contain a catalytic amount of cuprous ion and if coumarin behaves in the same fashion as an α, β-unsaturated ketone, conjugate addition would occur to form enolate **6**. The enolate may well undergo elimination to afford ketene **7**, which, in turn, reacts with phenyl magnesium bromide to provide ketone enolate **8**. The professor's proposed displacement of phenoxide by the Grignard reagent at an sp<sup>2</sup> center is unwarranted. Workup with water would provide ketone **9** which has been converted to **10** upon acid catalysis. 
[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhQJx.jpg)

1) [J. N. Moothry, P. Venkatakrishnan, S. Sengupta and M. Baidya, *Organic Letters*, **2006**, *8*, 4891.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ol0619260)